# WCF service not reachable (selfhosted)

Tags: wcf, service, host

today i decided to have a look at WCF and the example worked so nicely on my localhost that i tried to run in on my server too, so i compiled it with the correct host(tested both,ip and domain) and uploaded it to my server

you can see the sourcecode here:
http://pastebin.com/YiCR0RCf

the problem is,that i can't add the service to my client application, nor can i open the http site in my browser (localhost it worked just fine)

i'm running this on a windows root server and disabled the firewall for this program.
Would be great if you could give me a hint in getting this to work correctly, as i spent the last 2 hours with randomly changing code and uploading the program hoping that it would work now.

Thanks

Comment: ok i just tried to open the http website on the server itself(starting firefox there), and this works,maybe it will help you

Comment: The other way is You can add .svc file and then add the ServiceReference.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was the windows firewall, i completely disabled it(added an exception before,but that didn't help as i know now) and it works.

thanks anyways